# Python nested parenthesis function parameter list invalid syntax

Tags: python-3.x

The code from the page [chaotic attractor reconstruction.](http://www.node99.org/tutorials/ar/) returns an error when running under Python 3.4.4 as follows:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

at the 2nd opening parenthesis in the parameter part of the function:

```
def rossler_odes((x, y, z), (a, b, c)):
    return numpy.array([-y - z, x + a * y, b + z * (x - c)])
```

I am guessing this could be a Python version issue e.g. code created for version older than 3.4.4. I do not know Python but I wish to run this to learn the physics and of course the language.

Comment: Consider using `tuples` or even `dictionaries` as arguments. Then you will have named arguments inside dictionary eg. `tup1['x'], tup2['a']` and so on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tuple parameter unpacking has been removed in Python 3, see [PEP 3113](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/), also [What's new in Python 3.0](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#removed-syntax). As  suggested there, the easiest way to make your code Python 2/3 compatible is to use

```
def rossler_odes(x_y_z, a_b_c):
    x, y, z = x_y_z
    a, b, c = a_b_c
    return numpy.array([-y - z, x + a * y, b + z * (x - c)])
```

Comment: Stephan, your answer is really valuable! It illustrates the concept perfectly.